# How I can build custom style for all xmls layout?

Tags: android

In my graduation project ...

Can I use css in android app ? if yes how ? 
How I can add two layout for one activity ?

Answer (score 0):

You case use CSS in an android application through a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). What I usually do is injecting some JavaScript code to add styles to my elements.

Basic example for resizing images:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(...);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl("javascript:"      
                     + "var styles = document.createElement('STYLE'); "
                     + "styles.innerHTML = 'img {width: ' + 200 + '; height:' + 200 + ';}';"
                 + "document.body.appendChild(styles);");
            }
        });
```